# Convert webp base64 to jpg/png base64 C#

Tags: c#, image, base64

i have a problem that the client has the webp saved in base64 in the database, but to print the image i needed it to be in jpg or png, with that i thought of taking the image, converting it to an byte array and converting the image, changing the base64 for printing.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64))))
{
   image.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Or Png
}
```

i've tried with this code, but after this i don't know what make, detail, i don't need to save the image, i only want the conversion and after return the base64 of jpg or png.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here.  And specifically, "but after this i don't know what make, detail, i don't need to save the image" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have a webp in base64 i needed to convert this to jpg or png base64, it was clear?

Comment: If `Image` here is from `System.Drawing` I don't think webp is a supported format. Also why cant you print the image if it is webp?

Comment: I don't cant print  webp because i using a NReco.PdfGenerator to convert my html to pdf, and apparently he not support print the webp, because i've tried any ways

Comment: perhaps try this code:  https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper

Comment: You should be able to save the image to a memory stream instead of a file, i.e. the reverse process from reading the image.

Comment: Yeah, it's possibile in this case i'm using the memorystream, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i solved the problem basically with this code

```
using System.IO;
using ImageMagick;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    using (var image = new MagickImage(stream))
    {
        // Convert the WebP image to a JPG image
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
            image.Quality = 80;
            image.Write(outputStream);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray());
        }
   }
```

}

i discover the [MagickImage Lib](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET), and record the image in memomry with the memoryStream, so with this i don't need save the image to migrate, because the image stay in the memory, she works well for that i need and solved this question, thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).